# Error: Cannot find module "react-dom"

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-dom

error while importing:

```
import { DataTable } from 'react-jquery-datatables';
```

terminal error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-jquery-datatables/node_modules/react-
dom/server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactDOMServer' in 
'/home/laith/workspace/mender-dashboard/node_modules/reac
t-jquery-datatables/node_modules/react-dom'
@ ./node_modules/react-jquery-datatables/node_modules/react-
dom/server.js 
3:17-52
@ ./node_modules/react-jquery-datatables/lib/Table.js
@ ./node_modules/react-jquery-datatables/lib/index.js
@ ./src/views/User/User.js
@ ./src/containers/Full/Full.js
@ ./src/index.js
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 
webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/index.js
```

tried to reinstall react-jquery-datatables and react-dom nothing happens

Comment: what you used to install `react-dom`?

Comment: @MayankShukla npm install react-dom --save-dev

Comment: check package.json file, if it was installed correctly you will find an entry here. Like this: `react-dom: version no` or hit `npm list react-dom` it will print the version.

Comment: npm list react-dom
└─┬ react-jquery-datatables@0.7.1
  └── react-dom@0.14.9

at package.json file - devDependencies      "react-dom": "^16.0.0",

Comment: Try with removing the curly brackets around the `DataTable`. Do this: `import DataTable from 'react-jquery-datatables'`

Comment: @ArslanTariq same error

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me by simply uninstalling and resintalling.  run below command.

```
npm uninstall react-dom a
```

and than

```
  npm install react-dom --save-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is related to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8588). `react/lib/ReactDOMServer` is replaced by `react-dom/server`. So try downgrading react to `0.14`. Make `react-dom` as a dependency, not as dev dependency, and ensure `NODE_ENV` is not set to production.

```
npm i react-dom@0.14.9 --save
```

Answer (score 1):

install both react and react dom, because react-dom needs react

npm i react

npm i react-dom